# cURL loop giving a 500 response

Tags: php, curl, while-loop

So I have a script which loops doing multiple cURL calls.  After about 7-9 minutes it randomly stops execution.  I have set the .user.ini file to adjust these settings:

```
max_execution_time = 30000
max_input_time = 200
```

I believe I have fastCGI but can't for the life of me figure out why this keeps dying on me.  I have a submit form on the front end and I just get a 500 when it dies with nothing in the error log.  Anything else I could be missing?  Some PHP setting somewhere limiting the number of cURLs or execution time?

EDIT:  So this issue was definitely FastCGI limiting my time with the param "FcgidBusyTimeout".  My hosting company upped it for me as a test and everything worked great.  The issue now is that because I'm on shared hosting they wont up FastCGI timeouts for people.  I'm going to try and loop my script onto itself (kind of like a function loop where it calls itself again) and see if the new process' get me past the timeout issue.

Comment: For me you should simple run one curl in each run and reload your script. Of course we don't know why you get 500 error. Maybe it is some way of blocking too many calls one after another from the same IP??

Comment: I don't think anything is limiting the calls.  I even broke up the script to make MORE calls but get less data each time.  I still get around the same amount of data and then breaks :/ ...the weirdest part is how its completely random!!  Always somewhere between 7-9 minutes though.  I'm stumped lol

Comment: What about memory_limit ?

Comment: It's set at 2 gigs and I'm being pretty careful about memory usage so it doesnt appear to be linked to memory

Answer (score 1):

FastCGI has its own timeout.

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    IPCConnectTimeout 20
    IPCCommTimeout 120
    FcgidBusyTimeout 200
</IfModule>
```

So if your PHP timeout is high enough its possible that your FastCGI process were killed after that time.

If you have heavy scripts its better to run the script over your CLI then you have only the PHP Timeout.

Comment: Yeah Im hosted on site5 under a shared server so I dont have access to fastcgi settings.  Im asking them about this issue though to have it changed.  As for CLI that wouldnt work since this needs to be run by other people at some point so i need hosted files(unless theres a way to use CLI im not aware of?)

Comment: FYI Stony they upped the time on "FcgidBusyTimeout" and it worked fine.  Thanks again for the input!

Comment: Ok. There are some options.